# Is it correct to access entity manager in entity class (to ensure no duplicate username)

Tags: validation, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to ensure no duplicate username's when validating my entity

```
/**
 * @var string $name
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=32)
 * @Assert\NotBlank();
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"isUniqueUsername"})
 */
private $name;
```

I suppose I need to use the Validator Callback. Then I will have to query database for users with that username, so I require entity manager? How do I access it? And access it "correctly"? Do I use a validator class instead? It seems quite troublesome to create a class just to validate 1 field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In symfony2, there is a Unique validator you can use to ensure that a username, email address or any other field is unique. When using annotations, it works like this:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints as Unique;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table
 * @Unique\UniqueEntity(fields={"email"},message="Your email is already registered")
 */
class User{
  // ...
}
```

When trying to add a user through a form, you should get the message stated in the Unique annotation.

Comment: If I need username, email & displayName to be unique, I will just put `fields={"username", "email", "displayName"}`? By unique I mean I should not have 2 identical usernames (I don't mean as a group, I suppose `UniqueEntity` is still what I need?)

Comment: From the top of my head I qould say you need to define 3 times Unique\UniqueEntity with one field at a time.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use the entity manager from within an entity - it breaks Separation of Concerns. Your entity class is a POPO (plain old PHP object) that should simply describe an entity - it should not be responsible for anything persistence related. If you need to run a custom query, do so either from a repository class, or a separate service. The repository class already has access to the entity manager. If you use a custom service, simply inject the entity manager into it.

Comment: In my case, which is more appropriate? Service or Repository? I'm validating for unique username/email